# windows mozilla dosen't support position absolue

Tags: css, windows, firefox

When I try to use position: absolute on a div in Firefox it doesn't seem to work.
For jquery calender I used `position:absolute` for a div it seems to work all browsers in linux and windows except mozilla in windows. When I remove the position:absolute it will work in windows firefox but only showing alternate months in all other browsers (january, march, may, ..)

```
 <div class="body">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="container a pickable month" style="z-index: 999; left: 0px; visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1; display: block;">
            <div class="row a odd">
                <div class="first">
                    Su</div>
                <div>
                    Mo</div>
                <div>
                    Tu</div>
                <div>
                    We</div>
                <div>
                    Th</div>
                <div>
                    Fr</div>
                <div class="last">
                    Sa</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row b even">
                <div class="outside first">
                    28</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    29</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    30</div>
                <div>
                    1</div>
                <div>
                    2</div>
                <div>
                    3</div>
                <div class="last">
                    4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row c odd">
                <div class="first">
                    5</div>
                <div>
                    6</div>
                <div>
                    7</div>
                <div>
                    8</div>
                <div>
                    9</div>
                <div>
                    10</div>
                <div class="last">
                    11</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row d even">
                <div class="first">
                    12</div>
                <div>
                    13</div>
                <div>
                    14</div>
                <div>
                    15</div>
                <div>
                    16</div>
                <div>
                    17</div>
                <div class="last">
                    18</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row e odd">
                <div class="first">
                    19</div>
                <div>
                    20</div>
                <div>
                    21</div>
                <div>
                    22</div>
                <div>
                    23</div>
                <div>
                    24</div>
                <div class="last">
                    25</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row f even">
                <div class="first">
                    26</div>
                <div>
                    27</div>
                <div>
                    28</div>
                <div>
                    29</div>
                <div>
                    30</div>
                <div>
                    31</div>
                <div class="outside last">
                    1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row g odd">
                <div class="outside first">
                    2</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    3</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    4</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    5</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    6</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    7</div>
                <div class="outside last">
                    8</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container b pickable month" style="z-index: 998; visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1; display: block; left: -200px;">
            <div class="row a odd">
                <div class="first">
                    Su</div>
                <div>
                    Mo</div>
                <div>
                    Tu</div>
                <div>
                    We</div>
                <div>
                    Th</div>
                <div>
                    Fr</div>
                <div class="last">
                    Sa</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row b even">
                <div class="outside first">
                    31</div>
                <div>
                    1</div>
                <div>
                    2</div>
                <div>
                    3</div>
                <div>
                    4</div>
                <div>
                    5</div>
                <div class="last">
                    6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row c odd">
                <div class="first">
                    7</div>
                <div>
                    8</div>
                <div>
                    9</div>
                <div>
                    10</div>
                <div>
                    11</div>
                <div>
                    12</div>
                <div class="last">
                    13</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row d even">
                <div class="first">
                    14</div>
                <div>
                    15</div>
                <div>
                    16</div>
                <div>
                    17</div>
                <div>
                    18</div>
                <div>
                    19</div>
                <div class="last">
                    20</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row e odd">
                <div class="first">
                    21</div>
                <div>
                    22</div>
                <div>
                    23</div>
                <div>
                    24</div>
                <div>
                    25</div>
                <div>
                    26</div>
                <div class="last">
                    27</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row f even">
                <div class="first">
                    28</div>
                <div>
                    29</div>
                <div>
                    30</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    1</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    2</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    3</div>
                <div class="outside last">
                    4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row g odd">
                <div class="outside first">
                    5</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    6</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    7</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    8</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    9</div>
                <div class="outside">
                    10</div>
                <div class="outside last">
                    11</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style sheet is http://snagglefoot.net/ainc/calendar-eightysix-default.css

Comment: Why are you not using a table?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Can you post what it was if you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying a width or top or left property for the div in question if you did not in the original code.

Position is commented out here. Maybe you didn't mean to.

```
.calendar-eightysix .body {
        position: relative;
    }
        .calendar-eightysix .body .inner .container {
            /*position: absolute;*/
            left: 0;
        }
```